# Roboto Flex variable font in greek

Tags: fonts, roboto, variable-fonts

I'm searching Roboto Flex with greek characters

https://github.com/TypeNetwork/Roboto-Flex

Does anybody knows how to find more charsets?

Answer (score 0):

Drop a TTF into https://wakamaifondue.com/beta/ to find out what it supports.

Answer (score 0):

No Greek character is available in Google Fonts: https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Roboto+Flex

You will have to wait for more research.